# Why am I getting this code Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") : argument "body" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I have this issue, I already emailed my professor for help. All he said was I need to change things in the dashboard body. here is the code for the body. I don't see what I am missing. I basically copied the book line for line, but I cannot find the issue. and i have no clue what i am doing.

```
 dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
        column(width=6, 
               box(
                   title = "Select a Number",
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   background = "yellow",
                   status="warning",
                   width = NULL,
                   height = 312,
                   sliderInput(inputId = "number",
                               label = "", 
                               value = 500, min = 25, max = 1000)),
               
               box(title = "Histogram",
                   solidHeader=TRUE, 
                   background = "light-blue",
                   status="primary",
                   width = NULL,
                   plotOutput("hist", height = 250)),
               valueBoxOutput("meanBox"),
               valueBoxOutput("medianBox"),
               valueBoxOutput("sdBox")
        ),
        
tabItem(
tabName = "normal",
fluidRow(
    box(title = "selecta Number",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        status = "warning",
        sliderInput(inputId = "normnumber",
                    label = "",
                    value = 500,min = 25, max = 1000)),
    box(title = "Destiny Plot",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        background = "light-blue",
        status = "primary",
        plotOutput("density", height = 250)),
    infoBoxOutput("meanInfoBox"),
    infoBoxOutput("medianInfoBox"),
    infoBoxOutput("sdInfoBox")
        )
),
        column(width = 6, 
               
               tabBox(
                   title = "Central Tendency",
                   id = "tabs1", height = 120, width = NULL,
                   tabPanel("Mean",
tabBox(
title = "Variability",
id = "tabs2",height = 120, width = NULL,
side = "right",
tabPanel("Variance",
h2(textOutput("vartext")),width = NULL),
tabPanel("Standard Deviation", h2(textOutput("sdtext")), width = NULL)
```

Comment: You may have extra comma (a trailing `,`) or extra / missing bracket `)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many ending `(`. Here is the fixed code:

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=6, 
           box(
             title = "Select a Number",
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "yellow",
             status="warning",
             width = NULL,
             height = 312,
             sliderInput(inputId = "number",
                         label = "", 
                         value = 500, min = 25, max = 1000)),
           
           box(title = "Histogram",
               solidHeader=TRUE, 
               background = "light-blue",
               status="primary",
               width = NULL,
               plotOutput("hist", height = 250)),
           valueBoxOutput("meanBox"),
           valueBoxOutput("medianBox"),
           valueBoxOutput("sdBox")
    ),
    
    tabItem(
      tabName = "normal",
      fluidRow(
        box(title = "selecta Number",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            status = "warning",
            sliderInput(inputId = "normnumber",
                        label = "",
                        value = 500,min = 25, max = 1000)),
        box(title = "Destiny Plot",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            background = "light-blue",
            status = "primary",
            plotOutput("density", height = 250)),
        infoBoxOutput("meanInfoBox"),
        infoBoxOutput("medianInfoBox"),
        infoBoxOutput("sdInfoBox")
      )
    ),
    column(width = 6, 
           
           tabBox(
             title = "Central Tendency",
             id = "tabs1", height = 120, width = NULL,
             tabPanel("Mean",
                      tabBox(
                        title = "Variability",
                        id = "tabs2",height = 120, width = NULL,
                        side = "right",
                        tabPanel("Variance",
                                 h2(textOutput("vartext")),width = NULL),
                        tabPanel("Standard Deviation", h2(textOutput("sdtext")), width = NULL)
                      )
            )
        )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but now  i am receiving ui not found error

Comment: I forgot to put the UI code in the beginning but now it is the original error